# report an update in parent version to sonar or jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, versions-maven-plugin

When a maven build has a parent that is not the latest release version, the goal of the versions plugin display-parent-updates is reporting it nicely but I would like to report this somehow:

1. mark the build with a WARNING or UNSTABLE status (to have a colored visual in jenkins)
2. add this in the jacoco report (no idea if this is possible, would be great)-> to be visible in sonar
3. maybe use the enforcer plugin (don't know if this would help)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I achieved this in 2 steps : 

1. Use of the following plugin 

`<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>display-dkv-boot-starter-parent-updates</id>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>display-parent-updates</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>`
```

2. Use of the enforce plugin with a custom rule

   public class MyCustomRule implements EnforcerRule2 {

   ```
        private boolean fail = false;

        @Override
        public void execute(EnforcerRuleHelper helper) throws EnforcerRuleException {
            Log log = helper.getLog();
            List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList();
            try {
                Path path = Paths.get((String) helper.evaluate("${versions.outputFile}"));
                lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
                fail = lines.stream()
                            .anyMatch(l -> l.contains("The parent project has a newer version"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.warn(ex);
                fail = false;
            }

            if (this.fail) {
                throw new EnforcerRuleException(lines.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCacheable() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isResultValid(EnforcerRule enforcerRule) {
            return fail;
        }

        @Override
        public String getCacheId() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public EnforcerLevel getLevel() {
            return EnforcerLevel.WARN;
        }
    }
   ```